Angular 19: 'imports' is only valid on a component that is standalone
I am migrating my angular library from v18 to v19.
Before upgrade components looked like following:

@Component({
    selector: "custom-component",
    templateUrl: "./custom.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./custom.component.scss"],
    standalone: true,
    imports: [
        MatIconModule,
        CommonModule,
        ... other imports
    ],

Since after upgrade standalone: true is removed in migration process referred here in official Angular Docs.
Now after upgrade I am getting error:
'imports' is only valid on a component that is standalone.(-992010)
my component after automatic upgrade looks like this:

@Component({
    selector: "custom-component",
    templateUrl: "./custom.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./custom.component.scss"],
    imports: [
        MatIconModule,
        CommonModule,
        ... other imports
    ],

Any help is appreciated.
I have updated angular-language-service and also restarted vs-code but nothing helped.

Can you try to remove your node_modules and reinstall all the packages? It sounds like it still gets stuck at version 18

Looking at the github issues related to this:

The LS does not recognise components as being standalone #2119

Problem with new project scaffolding and standalone being default to true #58765




You can uninstall/reinstall angular language service.

You can open your project as the root project in VSCode, if you open a workspace with multiple projects, it confuses angular language service as to which angular version is correct to use.

Try deleting .angular (Cache folder) and checking after restarting VSCode.



This! You can open your project as the root project in VSCode, if you open a workspace with multiple projects, it confuses angular language service as to which angular version is correct to use.
Do you know any other way to solve this, other than closing all my opened projects?

@Kombye it is still in discussions on the GitHub issues, you can raise a GitHub issue on angular language plugin GitHub page to get their updates
